# Concatenating rows of data to add totals together

Tags: sql, oracle

The data returned from my query below is splitting hours for 1 day into 2 rows (there's a lunch deduction which accounts for the divide).

How do I concatenate the totals so that they appears on 1 line?

Perhaps I need to make the startdtm and enddtm appear all on 1 line rather than to separate out into 2 different rows that way the total column will be for the entire day?

I'm not sure how to do this - sorry the format may not be correct, I'm teaching myself as I go along.

```
select 
    a.employeeid
    , b.personfullname
    , c.payrulename
    , to_char(a.startdtm, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
    , to_char(a.startdtm, 'hh24:mi')
    , to_char(a.enddtm, 'hh24:mi')
    , ((a.enddtm - artdtm)*24*60/60) "TOTAL"        
from
    timesheetitem a
    , vp_timesheetitmv42 b
    , vp_employeev42 c
where
    a.startdtm = b.startdtm
    and a.employeeid = c.employeeid
    and a.employeeid = b.employeeid
    and payrulename = CA Ex
```

RESULTS

```
EEID    PERSON NAME     Payrule Eff Date    InPunch OutPunch    TOTAL
14065   Escobar, Test   CA Ex   7/1/2013    6:15    12:00        5.75
14065   Escobar, Test   CA Ex   7/1/2013    13:00   14:45        1.75
14065   Escobar, Test   CA Ex   7/2/2013    6:30    11:30        5
14065   Escobar, Test   CA Ex   7/2/2013    12:30   15:00        2.5
```

Comment: >EEID PERSON NAME Payrule Eff Date InPunch OutPunch TOTAL

Comment: Use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: >14065    Escobar, Test     CA Ex    6:15     12:00   5.75

Comment: What are these comments supposed to mean? If you want to clarify the question, do it by editing the question, not by putting random comments.

Comment: Do you need one row of output per `EEID` per `Eff Date`, or do you need the rows you are showing, and just the total needs to be the true total for the day? If it is the former, then obviously `InPunch` and `OutPunch` can't be in the output; if it's the latter, the `total` will be for the day, not for that specific row. You need to specify explicitly which of these two options you need. (Or, actually, there is a third alternative: show exactly what you have now, plus one more column for the daily total.)

Comment: MySQL? Oracle? *Both*? If it's not both, please edit your post and delete the inapplicable tag.

Comment: I need to have 1 total for the entire day showing the in/out times. Currently I have a "total" column but it is totaling each row rather than the entire day because the time is split between 2 rows.

Comment: @mathguy I'm guessing Oracle by the double quotes used to escape the aliases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I am guessing the same. The only language I am familiar with is Oracle, and I have found that everything I've looked at that is not Oracle looks unfamiliar to me. But we shouldn't have to guess; this seems to be a new forum member, it's best if he/she gets in the habit of managing post tags properly. :-)

Comment: Clark: Sorry, your answer doesn't make sense to me. What do you mean by ONE row showing total for the day AND the in-out times? There are two in-times and two out-times, how do you want those shown in a single row? Please edit your post and add a sample "output row" **exactly** as you think it should look like - don't worry about how that can be generated in code.

Comment: Because it's a timecard it's going to pull all in/out times. I'm working in Oracle SQL Developer                                                                       EEID PERSON NA    Payrule Eff Date InPunch OutPunch TOTAL
    14065 Escobar, Test CA Ex 7/1/2013 6:15 12:00      5.75
    14065 Escobar, Test CA Ex 7/1/2013 13:00 14:45    1.75  14065     Escobar  Test  CA Ex   7/1/2013   6:15  12:00 13:00 14:45   Daily total  = 7.50

Comment: The daily total is the sum of the 2 rows for each employee.For ex. for Escobar it's 5.75 + 1.75 = 7.50 TOTAL for 7/1

Comment: So, in the same row you show punch-in, then punch-out time, and then again punch-in and punch-out time? That can be done; are you guaranteed that a person doesn't punch in and out more than twice every day?

Comment: Yes, at the most there will be 4 punches. (They can also have 2 punches - 1 in and 1 out only)

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense. Now: you have a `startdtm` and an `enddtm` in table `timesheetitem`. That makes sense. What's the `startdtm` column in `vp_timesheetitmv42`? I see you are joining by `employeeid` as well as this `startdtm` field - will one table have a `startdtm` for a given employee, that is not also in the other table? How are these two tables related by `startdtm`?

Comment: Startdtm and Enddtm and employee id are all in both timesheetitem and vp_timesheetitmv42 tables. Payrule is not in either table which is why there's a 3rd table

Comment: Understood, but are the startdtm and enddtm values identical in the two tables, timesheetitem and vp_timesheetitmv42? If not, why not? Which takes precedence? If yes, why is the same data held in two different tables - and why do you need the first table anyway?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you have in mind:

```
select a.employeeid as EEID,
       b.personfullname as "PERSON NAME",
       c.payrulename as Payrule,
       to_char(a.startdtm, 'mm-dd-yyyy') as "EFF DATE",
       SUM((a.enddtm - artdtm)*24*60/60) as "TOTAL"        
from timesheetitem a
inner join vp_timesheetitmv42 b
    on a.startdtm = b.startdtm and
       a.employeeid = b.employeeid
inner join vp_employeev42 c
    on a.employeeid = c.employeeid
where payrulename = 'CA Ex'
group by a.employeeid,
         b.personfullname,
         c.payrulename,
         to_char(a.startdtm, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing it all in comments - here is an answer with the "agreement" so far. This may be in the direction of what you need.

The most deeply nested subquery attaches a number to each "in-out" pair (for fixed employeeid and calendar day); it may be the number 1, and in some cases it may be 2. Then I use this to create the single-row summaries which show in and out times (either just once or sometimes twice in the same day) and the total hours for the day. The rest is simple joins - using the ANSI standard syntax; you can adjust the joins as needed (I made a note about the point I'm confused on - the presence of `startdtm` and `enddtm` in the first AND in the second table).

I "invented" one more employee to show how this should be written to accommodate more than one employee, and to show the result if there are only one in-time and one out-time in a day.

```
with
     timesheetitem ( employeeid, startdtm, enddtm ) as (
       select 14065, to_date('7/1/2013 6:15' , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
                   , to_date('7/1/2013 12:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
       select 14065, to_date('7/1/2013 13:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
                   , to_date('7/1/2013 14:45', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
       select 14065, to_date('7/2/2013 6:30' , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
                   , to_date('7/2/2013 11:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
       select 14065, to_date('7/2/2013 12:30', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
                   , to_date('7/2/2013 15:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
       select 14068, to_date('7/2/2013 6:15' , 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
                   , to_date('7/2/2013 13:45', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
     ),
     vp_timesheetitmv42 ( employeeid, personfullname ) as (
       select 14065, 'Escobar, Test' from dual union all
       select 14068, 'Oracle, Maria' from dual
     ),
     vp_employeev42 ( employeeid, payrulename ) as (
       select 14065, 'CA Ex' from dual union all
       select 14068, 'CA Ex' from dual
     )
--  end of simulated data; SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select a.employeeid, b.personfullname, c.payrulename,
       a.eff_date, a.in_1, a.out_1, a.in_2, a.out_2, a.total as tot_hours
from   (
         select employeeid, to_char(startdtm, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as eff_date,
                to_char(min(startdtm), 'hh24:mi') as in_1, 
                to_char(min(enddtm)  , 'hh24:mi') as out_1,
                to_char(min(case rn when 2 then startdtm end), 'hh24:mi') as in_2,
                to_char(min(case rn when 2 then enddtm   end), 'hh24:mi') as out_2,
                24 * sum(enddtm - startdtm) as total
         from   (
                  select employeeid, startdtm, enddtm, 
                         row_number() over (partition by employeeid, trunc(startdtm) 
                                            order by startdtm) as rn
                  from   timesheetitem
                )
         group by employeeid, to_char(startdtm, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
       ) a
       join vp_timesheetitmv42 b on a.employeeid = b.employeeid
                                        --    and some condition on startdtm??
       join vp_employeev42     c on a.employeeid = c.employeeid
where  c.payrulename = 'CA Ex'
order by employeeid, eff_date, in_1     --  if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
EMPLOYEEID PERSONFULLNAME PAYRULENAME EFF_DATE   IN_1  OUT_1 IN_2  OUT_2  TOT_HOURS
---------- -------------- ----------- ---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----------
     14065 Escobar, Test  CA Ex       07/01/2013 06:15 12:00 13:00 14:45        7.5
     14065 Escobar, Test  CA Ex       07/02/2013 06:30 11:30 12:30 15:00        7.5
     14068 Oracle, Maria  CA Ex       07/02/2013 06:15 13:45                    7.5

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll adjust my query with your suggestions.